# why this piece code(some template stuff) compiled well in msvc10 but compiled failed in gcc4.8.1?

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

struct mystruct{};

template<typename T>
struct map;

//specification
#define MAPPING(Key, Val)       \
template<>                      \
struct map<Key>                 \
{                               \
    typedef Val mapping_type;   \
};

MAPPING(mystruct, int)

template<typename T>
void func(T t)
{
    map<T>::mapping_type i = 999;
    cout<<i<<endl;
}


int main() {
    // your code goes here
    mystruct ms;
    func(ms);

    return 0;
}
```

I try to do some type mapping(here mapping mystruct to int) via specification, but it can't compiled by gcc4.8.1, help!

**or what is the right way to accomplish this, thanks!**

http://ideone.com/yefbtk

Here are the error messages:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘void func(T)’:
prog.cpp:23:2: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘map<T>::mapping_type’ because ‘map<T>’ is a dependent scope
  map<T>::mapping_type i = 999;
  ^
prog.cpp:23:23: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘i’
  map<T>::mapping_type i = 999;
                       ^
prog.cpp:24:8: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
  cout<<i<<endl;
        ^
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void func(T) [with T = mystruct]’:
prog.cpp:31:9:   required from here
prog.cpp:23:2: error: dependent-name ‘map<T>::mapping_type’ is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
  map<T>::mapping_type i = 999;
  ^
prog.cpp:23:2: note: say ‘typename map<T>::mapping_type’ if a type is meant
```

Comment: `error: need ‘typename’ before ‘map<T>::mapping_type’ because ‘map<T>’ is a dependent scope` - that's pretty explicit. Why don't you try that?

Comment: Because `msvc10` does not follow Standard unlike `gcc`. `gcc` is correct, you do need `typename` there.

Comment: sorry, it just work well after ‘typename’ added. didn't catch the error messages..

Comment: agree with mike, the error is because mcvc take map<T>::mapping_type as a type not a data member by default, but gcc need to define that explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mat pointed out in the comments, you must include typename before using map::mapping_type.

```
template<typename T>
void func(T t)
{
    typename map<T>::mapping_type i = 999;
    cout<<i<<endl;
}
```